# Displaying the relative path of the currently edited file in Vim's statusline?

Tags: vim

`:help statusline` claims `%f` will render as:

> Path to the file in the buffer, as typed or relative to current directory.

When I `set statusline=%f`, the path in the statusline is sometimes relative, but often absolute.

Is there a way to make sure the path displayed is always relative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you could try this:

```
set stl+=%{expand('%:~:.')}
```

The expression inside `%{}` should be evaluated and added to your statusline. Here the expression is:

```
expand('%:~:.')
```

... which expands the name of the current file, but prevents the expansion of the tilde (`:~`), and makes the path relative to the current working directory (`:.`).

Comment: @user852573 Can you print [No Name] if %f expands to empty?

Comment: @user852573 Never mind, I got that. set statusline=\ %{expand('%:~:.')!=#''?expand('%:~:.'):'[No\ Name]'}

Answer (score 4):

Just below the explanation of `%f`, you will find explanation of `F`. Using `%F` instead of `%f` will give you the desired display.

```
item  meaning ~
f S   Path to the file in the buffer, as typed or relative to current
      directory.
F S   Full path to the file in the buffer.
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, that will render the *full* (i.e. absolute) path, whereas I'm looking to render the *relative* path (since the absolute form is simply too long to be helpful in some of my repos).

Comment: Your questions seems to say otherwise

Comment: Thanks, I noticed a typo in the last line, so I fixed it. The title was correct - I am looking to always display the **relative** path.

Answer (score 0):

you can type `:!echo %` to view path in shell

and `:pwd` shows the current working directory of vim

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that will work in the command line.